# TextFormField ignores any text change after picking image

Tags: flutter, binding, textinput

I've been scratching my head on this. Perhaps someone can help.
I have a statefull widget with a TextFormField and a button that calls the ImagePicker.pickImage function.
When I write something in the textformInput and then click on the select image button, when the image select returns from the picking, the textformfield has the text before I wrote.
It seems the onChanged function is never called when I press the button, so I cannot update my model variable.
I also tried to listen for focus out event on the textformfield widget but it also doesnt get called.
What am I missing? Any tip would be great.
Thanks

```
TextFormField(
  keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
  maxLines: 5,
  controller: _observationsFieldController,
  onChanged: (String value) {
    onFieldChanged(_observationsFieldController, value);
    widget.user_file.observations = value;
  },
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal:10, vertical: 2),
    hintText: 'Observations',
    suffix: clearSuffix(_observationsFieldController),
  ),
),
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using setState()? Since you are updating the state, it might work when you call set state.

Comment: Yes I did. The thing is that the onChange is not called when I press the button. I was able to solve it by saving the textinputs text individually on the button press function before calling the image picker and setting the state again when returning from that image pick navigator pop, but I dont think it should be necessary since the onChange should be triggered on losing focus and it isnt doing it. Thank you for your suggestion.